# How to remove navigation bar's shadow

Tags: objective-c, ios, uinavigationbar

I have UINavigationBar.

```
UINavigationBar *navBar = [[UINavigationBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 46.0f, 320.0f, 50.0f)];
navBar.tintColor = [UIColor blackColor];
[self.view addSubview:navBar];
```

And I want to remove standart top shadow. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define a custom image for the navbar in iOS 5.0 and above:

```
UIImage *backgroundImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"bevel_nav_bar.png"];
[navBar setBackgroundImage:backgroundImage forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

Comment: It's probably great :) but I interested in way without using background image.

Comment: I'm unsure if there is actually a way to just remove the shadow.. maybe try something like this to just draw the color you want? (unsure if it removes shadow too) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4904877/remove-gradient-on-uinavigationbar