# Making UIToolBar ans UISearchBar have a matte black background

Tags: ios, ios5, uikit, uitoolbar

Can I do this without overriding the `drawRect` method?

I've tried the following:

```
UIImage *navBarImage = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"image_navbg.png"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(5, 5, 5, 5)];
[self.descriptionBar setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:navBarImage]];
[self.bottomBar setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:navBarImage]];
```

Where image_navbg.png is a solid matte black square. The result I get still has a black - gray gradient.

Also setting these did not help:

```
[self.descriptionBar setTranslucent:YES];
[self.bottomBar setTranslucent:YES];
```

Comment: Check this answer  - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4904877/remove-gradient-on-uinavigationbar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you’re targeting iOS 5, use [UIAppearance](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIAppearance_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) for this — don’t override `-drawRect:` anymore.

Answer (score 3):

I wanted to do the same thing with the toolbar that's *built-in* to the navigation controller. You reveal it using:

```
[self.navigationController setToolbarHidden:NO];
```

In order to remove the gradient on *this* kind of toolbar (in iOS 4 and earlier at least), I used the following technique with success. First I added this to my appDelegate header:

```
@interface MyToolbar : UIToolbar {}

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect;

@end
```

Then I added this to my appDelegate .m file

```
@implementation MyToolbar

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    UIColor *colorTabBlack = [UIColor colorWithRed:0 green:0 blue:0 alpha:1];
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextSetFillColor(context, CGColorGetComponents( [colorTabBlack CGColor]));
    CGContextFillRect(context, rect);
}
@end
```

Then in IB I switched the (now visible) toolbar's class to "MyToolbar" - it took me forever to figure this out, which is why I'm posting it. Hope it helps someone else!

Answer (score 0):

This is the way I did it.  Worked great for me.  You might have to try different indexes in your subviews.

```
// Change color of searchbar
[[self.searchbar.subviews objectAtIndex:0] removeFromSuperview];
self.searchbar.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];

// Change color of toolbar
[[self.toolbar.subviews objectAtIndex:0] removeFromSuperview];
self.toolbar.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
```