# Remove white gradient from Navigationbar on iOS6

Tags: ios, ios6, uinavigationbar

I am trying to remove the white gradient from the top of the `navigationBar`on `iOS6.`
How can I do this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried setting the background image on the navigation bar?

try using setBackgroundImage:forBarMetrics: and setting an image without the gradient.

Maybe use the code from the answer to this question to create a solid colour image:

[How to create a colored 1x1 UIImage on the iPhone dynamically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/990976/how-to-create-a-colored-1x1-uiimage-on-the-iphone-dynamically)

Answer (score 1):

Another somewhat hack-ish solution is mentioned here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4904939/171933

The background image seems like the cleaner solution.